# JavaScript — Array is getting filled with a bunch of "undefined"s

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to implement selection sort to get my hands dirty with arrays (note: I'm aware that there's a built-in sorting function). I'm running into some strange behavior, though.

Here's my code:

```js
function selectionSort(array)
{
    let currentMin = 0;
    var minIndex = 0;

    function swap(array, i, j)
    {
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    {
        console.log(array);
        currentMin = array[i];
        minIndex = i;

        for(var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] < currentMin)
            {
                currentMin = array[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if(minIndex != i)
        {
            swap(array, i, j);
        }
    }

    console.log(array);

    return array;
}

var myArray = [2, 50, 8, 4, 3, -400, 12, 120];
var sorted = selectionSort(myArray);
document.write('<p>Unsorted: ' + String(myArray) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>Sorted: ' + String(sorted) + '</p>');
```

The result:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of a few of the logs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that's causing all those `undefined`s to appear?

Comment: One key problem I can see up-front is that you seem to assume that `selectionSort` creates a new array. It doesn't. It returns the same one that you passed into it. So your "Unsorted" and "Sorted" are the same, since you're outputting those after calling `selectionSort`, and they're both outputting the same array.

Comment: When you're doing `for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)`, after the loop `j` ends up beyond the max index from your array due to the last `j++`. Therefore you're passing an out of bounds index to `swap`.

Comment: as T. Crowder wrote: putting a return in this function is an error, because the function acts directly on the array data

Comment: @MrJ Well, returning the array isn't an *error*. It just doesn't make sense to do it because the array passed in gets directly modified.

Comment: yeah, that correct, this is just bad programming ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
swap(array, i, j);
```

When you call that, `j` is `array.length` and so `array[j]` is `undefined`, since you're beyond the end of the array.

I think you meant:

```
swap(array, i, minIndex);
// ------------^^^^^^^^
```

With that change, and outputting the array before sorting it for the "Unsorted" line rather than after:

```js
function selectionSort(array)
{
    let currentMin = 0;
    var minIndex = 0;

    function swap(array, i, j)
    {
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    {
        console.log(array);
        currentMin = array[i];
        minIndex = i;

        for(var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            if(array[j] < currentMin)
            {
                currentMin = array[j];
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if(minIndex != i)
        {
            swap(array, i, minIndex);
        }
    }

    console.log(array);

    return array;
}

var myArray = [2, 50, 8, 4, 3, -400, 12, 120];
document.write('<p>Unsorted: ' + String(myArray) + '</p>');
selectionSort(myArray);
document.write('<p>Sorted: ' + String(myArray) + '</p>');
```

---

It's important to understand that `selectionSort` operates on the array **in-place**, it doesn't create a new array. From your original code, you  seemed to think it did:

```
var myArray = [2, 50, 8, 4, 3, -400, 12, 120];
var sorted = selectionSort(myArray);
document.write('<p>Unsorted: ' + String(myArray) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>Sorted: ' + String(sorted) + '</p>');
```

`sorted` and `myArray` both point to the same array (`sorted === myArray` is true), which is why both lines showed the array's contents *after* `selectionSort` was used on it, even the "Unsorted" line.

If you wanted to return a *new* array, you could start out by copying the array in `selectionSort` like this:

```
array = array.slice();
```

Or in modern environments, `array = Array.from(array);`.

But if you're creating a new array, an insertion sort would probably be more efficient than this sorting algorithm. (There are other algorithms for in-place sorts as well, most of which are more efficient than this one for most input data.)

Comment: Thank you for all the valuable info! I'm used to languages like C++ and Java. I'll have to revisit how JavaScript treats function arguments to avoid this in the future. (I plan to implement other sorts as well beyond selection sort—I just usually do that as an exercise when moving to a new language.)

Comment: @AlexH - If it helps, JavaScript handles function arguments and object references exactly the way Java handles method arguments and object references. Both are purely pass-by-value languages, and object references are values in both languages. (The languages are quite different in many other ways, but this is an area where they behave the same way.)

Comment: Thank you, that does help! I think C and C++ have ruined this for me, lol. I'm so used to explicitly passing by reference/pointer that this trips me up with languages like Python and such.